# Extracting assembly code from the ELF using Python

Tags: python, linux, assembly, extract, elf

I am trying to extract assembly code from the ELF file is there any Python pre-define library that can allow me to extract assembly code from the elf file like [Objdump](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objdump) do in Linux, for more I am writing this code to find a set of instruction from the binary file, if you give me a sample code.

Comment: assembly code is not in the elf file, the machine code is.  you then can disassemble it, which is not a trivial task

Comment: @bad_coder: note that the first edit to a closed question (other than just tags) will put it in the reopen review queue.  So usually it's a good idea to *not* do minor cosmetic edits like this when that won't make the question suitable for reopening.  It takes reviewer's time, and takes away the querent's chance to improve the question. (IDK if that would be possible in this case; it looks like either a request for a disassembler library, or a request to write one from scratch as an SO answer.)  If it's not the first edit after closing, then fine, the review queue isn't a factor.

Comment: @bad_coder: Oh, that change got implemented?  Great, nevermind then.  :)

Answer (score 1):

There is a library called `pyelftools`.

References:

https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/exploring-elf-files-using-pyelftools-93bb7665cce3

[https://github.com/eliben/pyelftools/wiki/User's-guide](https://github.com/eliben/pyelftools/wiki/User%27s-guide)